# Are the continuous linear functions from a norm space to R bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis

$\{X, \|\cdot\|\}$ a normed space, a function, maping from $X$ to $\mathbb R$, is linear and continuous. Is it  a bounded linear function?

Comment: Bounded in the sense of a bounded linear function, or a bounded function?

Comment: bounded linear function

Comment: The dual space $X^*$ consists of all bounded linear functionals on $X$, and so to answer your title, yes, the continuous linear functions in the dual of $X$ are bounded by definition.

Comment: Oh, I change the title, it's only continuous.